# After uploading a paper to arXiv, how much time does one have to change the papers' metadata without impacting the time in the submission history?

Tags: arxiv

Papers uploaded to arXiv have a time in the submission history E.g, https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05685: "Mon, 16 Apr 2018 13:55:20 UTC (185 KB)"

After uploading a paper to arXiv, how much time does one have to change the papers' metadata (title, abstract, authors, comments, subjects, etc.) without impacting the time displayed in the submission history?

I don't see the information in https://info.arxiv.org/help/availability.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong spot: https://info.arxiv.org/help/replace.html#same-day-edits-do-not-generate-a-new-version-stamp

Same day updates to the metadata do not impact the Submission History on the abstract pages as *only the last saved change* is recorded by the click of submit article. So if one updates the paper 5 times between the initial submission and the daily freeze on new submissions (occurs at 2pm Eastern), then only the last change is recorded. Updates beyond that time will push the submission into the next mailing, and will continue until that version is made public.

A new submission at that point will generate a new entry in the Submission History.

Some caveats: The addition of a [cross-listing](https://info.arxiv.org/help/cross.html) or addition of a Journal Reference/DOI/Report number through the [`jref` submission type](https://info.arxiv.org/help/jref.html) do not generate a new version. Administrative updates to the metadata (such as a correction of a typo) also do not generate a new version or alter the timestamp on the abstract page.

Comment: Thanks! " if one updates the paper 5 times between the initial submission and the daily freeze on new submissions (occurs at 2pm Eastern), then only the last change is recorded": will that the submission time shown on arXiv be the time of the initial submission or the time of the last update?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it will only ever be the *last* time "submit article" was clicked, as that would be the last time the author approved that version.

Comment: Thanks. Can one change the papers' metadata (title, abstract, authors, comments, subjects, etc.) without clicking on "submit article"?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It'd be like having an editor open and never clicking save... The changes wouldn't go anywhere. If the work were in ["submitted" status](https://info.arxiv.org/help/submission_status.html) and you were editing it, it'd be made public with the last changes committed at the "submit article". No changes are recorded until the changes are submitted.

Comment: Thanks, noted. I therefore understand that the answer to "How much time does one have to change the papers' metadata without impacting the time in the submission history?" is: no time. Any saved change to the papers' metadata will impact the time in the submission history: the submission time will be the time of the last saved change.

Comment: That's it, essentially. The time recorded in the stamp on Submission History is the last time the submitter clicked "submit article" for that version.